# How to add field with static value to mongodb find query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Can we add some custom field with static value to mongodb **find** query?

I am trying to add/append API request UId to all the queries that we are making to mongodb, so that  we can map requests with slow queries from mongodb logs.

I am doing it in aggregate queries by using `'$literal'` in projected fields.
My Aggregate queries looks something like :

```
db.test.aggregate({
    $project: {
        "custom_id": { $literal: "uid" } 
        ..
    }
    ..
})
```

Also I can't include each field individually in projected fields and add the "custom_id" field with the static value.

Comment: What is your MongoDB version?

Comment: MongoDB version is 3.2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `$comment`, you can give a try to the `aggregate` function and the `literal`:

```js
db.bids.aggregate( [
   { $project: { item: 1, startAt: { $literal: 1 } } }
] )
```

And as a result you get:

```js
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "abc123", "startAt" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "xyz123", "startAt" : 1 }
```

Doc: [`$literal`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/)

Answer (score -1):

Found answer to the question on mongoDb jira.
The best way to do this would be using the $comment operator.
Here's [the link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/comment/) to Documentation.