# how to add static column to mongo select statement

Tags: mongodb

I want to write a mongo statement which is equivalent to this SQL statement. I know how to grab all the columns from table, but not sure how to get a column with static value out. Here is **query:**

```
select a.* , "static_value1" from table_a a;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add field with static value to mongodb find query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610412/how-to-add-field-with-static-value-to-mongodb-find-query)

Comment: no $comment doesnt add anything to the o/p of the query. I want to get some static value out of the query, which is not in table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try to the following one by using `aggregate` and `literal`:

Let's say we have the following input:

```js
db.inventory.insertMany( [
  { item: "journal", status: "A", size: { h: 14, w: 21, uom: "cm" }, instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 } ] },
  { item: "notebook", status: "A",  size: { h: 8.5, w: 11, uom: "in" }, instock: [ { warehouse: "C", qty: 5 } ] },
  { item: "paper", status: "D", size: { h: 8.5, w: 11, uom: "in" }, instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 60 } ] },
  { item: "planner", status: "D", size: { h: 22.85, w: 30, uom: "cm" }, instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 40 } ] },
  { item: "postcard", status: "A", size: { h: 10, w: 15.25, uom: "cm" }, instock: [ { warehouse: "B", qty: 15 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 35 } ] }
]);
```

#### Calculated field:

And I want as a custom result something like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c6b7e7449a55d3136613f90"), "myCustomField" : true }
```

To achieve the custom field, which is `myCustomField` in this example:

```
db.inventory.aggregate([ { $project: { myCustomField: { $eq: ["$status", { $literal: "A" }] }} }]);
```

#### Custom static value field

If you do not want to have calculated fields, simply use the following expression:

```
db.inventory.aggregate([ { $project: { myCustomField: { $literal: "apple" } } }]);
```

Which results as:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c6b7e7449a55d3136613f8c"), "myCustomField" : "apple" }
```

Doc: [`$literal`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/)

Comment: seems to be a right solution, although i cant test it completely. i am not using pure mongo. I am using cosomsDB (azure). and it seems $literal is not supported on it. on settings, it does says "MongoDB 3.4 wire protocol".